# PHP. Calling function from a different class.

Tags: php, class, function

I am working with two classes: usuarios, preguntas.

In preguntas I store id_usuario which correspond to the id from user, ok. But sometimes I need to display more than the id, so I made a function in usuarios. php to print this info:

This is mi code for now

usuarios.php (I'm only including relevant code for this problem)

Código PHP:

```
function __construct($id){

    $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios  WHERE id = '".$id."'");
        while($item = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){                              
            $this->id = $item['id'];
            $this ->fid = $item['fid'];
            $this ->usuario = $item['alias'];
            $this ->password = $item['pass'];
            $this ->email = $item['mail'];
            $this ->fechar = $item['fechar'];
            $this ->ultima = $item['ultima'];
            $this ->img_src = $item['img_src'];
            $this ->reputacion =     $this ->fechar = $item['reputacion'];
        }
}




function miniatura(){
    $html_mini = "<div>$this->usuario</div>";
    return $html_mini;

}
```

pregunta.php (i'm only including relevant code for this problem)

Código PHP:

```
function get_autor(){


                $us = new usuario($item['id']);

            return $us->miniatura();
}



function imprimir_titular(){
    $html_t = '<h1 class="prg'.$this->id.'" >[ '.$this->id_eval_q.' ] '.$this->get_autor().' pregunta: '.$this->pregunta.' , '.$this->fecha.'</h1>';
    return $html_t;
}
```

And this is the error:

Cita:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   usuario::miniatura() in
>   /home/piscolab/public_html/keepyourlinks.com/recetorium/clases/pregunta.php
>   on line 35 No entiendo por qué no
>   accede al método de la clase usuarios,
>   aunque me deje crear el objeto usuario
>   :S

Details:
- Protected atributes

Any help will be wellcome

Comment: Where is the definition of the `usuario` class? Is it supposed to be around the first code snippet?

Comment: try making the method "public". - public function miniatura(){ }

Comment: i tried making it public and it gives me an error 'unexpedted T_string public' :S

Comment: the definition of usuarios it's included in the main file (i tried including it aswell in the pregunta class but it gives me an error 'you cant redeclare __construct....' so it's included propperly :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied you code, change content of methods and everything works

```
    class usuario {
function __construct($id){

    echo 'ok';
}




function miniatura(){
    echo 'ok';

}   

}




function get_autor(){


                $us = new usuario($item['id']);

            return $us->miniatura();
}
```

Show full classes because with Your code as shown in nothing wrong.

Comment: does what i provided is enough?

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is the file where i'm calling both:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Recetorium > Preguntas - Pregunta o responde qué y cómo cocinar algo

Cargando..

and in router.php

```
<?php require_once('funciones.php');
```

if(isset($_POST['inicio'])){

```
// el usuario está iniciando sesion         

$iniciando = new sesion_usuarios();
if($iniciando->iniciar()){
    imprimir_sesion_iniciada();
}else{
    imprimir_formulario_sesion();
}
```

}else if(isset($_POST['registro'])){
 $registrando = new registro_usuarios();
    if($registrando->register()){
        imprimir_usuario_registrado();
    }else{
        imprimir_formulario_registro();
    }

}else if(isset($_GET['que']) or isset($que)){

```
    if(isset($que))
        $tarea = $que;
    else
        $tarea = $_GET['que'];

    if($tarea == 'registro'){
        imprimir_formulario_registro();
    }else if($tarea == 'login'){
        imprimir_formulario_sesion();
    }else if($tarea == 'salir'){
        cerrar_sesion();
    }else if($tarea == 'ultimas_preguntas'){
        listar_preguntas();
    }else if($tarea == 'nueva_pregunta'){
        $tem = new pregunta();
        $tem->imprimir_formulario;
    }else if($tarea == 'ultimas_recetas'){
        $tem = new pregunta();
        $tem->imprimir_formulario;
    }
```

}else if(sesion()){
    echo 'Pronto prodrás: Preguntar cosas, responder cosas y evaluar ambos. Publicar tus recetas, descubrir otras, evaluarlas y ser evaluado.';
}else{
    $archivo = 'bienvenida.php';
    include($archivo);
    imprimir_formulario_sesion();

}

?>